# Unix: Forks to a tree

Tags: c, unix, fork

I'm a newbie at unix shell programming and I have a really hard time getting an good explanation about forks and their trees. All I know for now is that a fork kind of copies a process (child) from the main one (parent).

More specifically I can't quite get from a piece of code how a process tree would be like.

For example, at this backbone of code:

```
pid1=fork();
if (pid1!=0) 
{   
    pid2=fork(); 
    pid3=fork(); 
}
else 
{ 
    pid4=fork(); 
}
```

It seems to me that there are 3 processes under the original process (pid1, pid2, pid3) and a child of one of these three (pid4), maybe pid2's.

I tried to run it with some more awfully written code:

```
int pid1, pid2, pid4, pid4;

printf("I'm the original Process %d with parent %d \n", getpid(), getppid());

pid1=fork();

if(pid1!=0)
{
    pid2=fork();
    printf("I'm P2 %d with parent %d \n", getpid(), getppid());
    sleep(1);

    pid3=fork();
    printf("I'm P3 %d with parent %d \n", getpid(), getppid());
    sleep(1);
}
else
{
    pid4=fork();
    printf("I'm P4 %d with parent %d \n", getpid(), getppid());
    sleep(1);
}
```

Edit: I put some sleep(1) at the code above, thanks to dbush, so I can see the ppid's

[image]

So, how is the tree forming with these types of code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why there are many PIDs printed while using fork system call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19323483/why-there-are-many-pids-printed-while-using-fork-system-call)

Comment: Nitpick: the code you show doesn't produce the output you show; there are newlines in the output that aren't present in the source.  It's really frustrating trying to debug the wrong code.  You should probably add a 'while' loop to `wait()` for children to die.  For example, `int corpse; int status; while ((corpse = wait(&status)) != -1) { …print information about dead child… }`.  This would give you better information about the tree structure.  The parent process 1 is the system process that waits for orphaned processes to exit.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I believe sleep(1)'s have kinda sort out the problem of ppid=1, is that right?

Comment: I can't see any `sleep(1)` calls in your code — so I can't tell whether it will work OK or not.  Please remind yourself about how to create an MCVE ([MCVE]) — you've been around long enough to have an idea what I'm talking about.

Comment: I've updated the code

Comment: For future reference: there are three distinct groups of results from `fork()` that you should be looking out for: 0 (success, and this is the child), positive (success, this is the parent, and the return value is the child's pid), and negative (failure; there is no child).

Comment: @cHao This is extremely helpful and straight to the point. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

You'll get a total of 5 children:

```
                  c2--------------
                    |             
                    |             
     c1---------------------------
       |           p4             
       |                          
       |                          
       |                          
       |                c5--------
       |                  |       
       |                  |       
       |       c3-----------------
       |         |       p3       
       |         |                
       |         |      c4--------
       |         |        |       
       |         |        |       
p---------------------------------
      p1        p2       p3
```

The first fork happens at point `p1`, which create child `c1`.  This child goes into the `else` part of the code and runs the fork at point `p4`, creating child `c2`.

Back in the parent, it forks at point `p2` creating child `c3`.  *Both* of these processes then fork at point `p3`, creating children `c4` and `c5`.

The reason you're seeing some processes report their parent as 1 is because the parent is finishing before the child.  Try putting `sleep(1)` at the bottom of this block to give the parent processes time to stay around so the children can see them.

Comment: Based on your answer and the pid's & ppid's I got with sleep(1), is this the tree that gets created? http://i65.tinypic.com/15nu8gh.png

Comment: No; your diagram seems to have 3 lines coming out of 'shell', which is at best confusing and most likely just wrong.