# Who runs first after fork() on real_time processes?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel

In Linux kernel 2.6.39.4, the `sched_fork()` will call the corresponding `task_fork()`, which is not implemented by `sched_rt` class. While in `sched_fair` class, `task_fork_()` will make sure the child runs first if `sysctl_sched_child_runs_first` is set. What about `sched_rt`? Does it mean the `sysctl_sched_child_runs_first` has no effect on the real time processes?

```c
    if (sysctl_sched_child_runs_first && curr && entity_before(curr, se)) {
        // make sure the child runs first
        swap(curr->vruntime, se->vruntime);
        resched_task(rq->curr);
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Who executes first after fork(): parent or the child?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8494732/608639) and [Can the order of execution of fork() be determined?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6696959/608639)