# Factorial using fork in C

Tags: c, fork, factorial

I want to write a program in C using fork method to compute n factorial. this program (process) creates only **one child**.
Each of the processes (parent and child) will compute approximately half of the complete sequence. Then the parent combines the results and print the final result.

- I've got an idea which is to divide the numbers between 1 to n into two intervals [1,n/2], [n/2,n] and assign the job of each interval to a process but i'm not so familiar with fork.

How can I pass data between the two processes?

Comment: So, your question is that you'd like someone to explain `fork()`? or... what exactly?

Comment: @Mike I wan't some piece of code that does the job. I kinda know the algorithm in general (I've put the idea) but I'm not aware of how to use fork in C and how to pass the partial result from the child to the parent.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12430461/how-to-use-fork-in-an-if-statement Does this help?

Comment: @AdrianPanasiuk I know what `fork()` does but I just want to know how to program `fork()` in C with passing data from child to parent and vice versa.

Comment: @Ibrahim.I I see, in that case I'll add the missing piece of the question into the post

Answer (score 1):

Don't use fork, but rather use pthreads.  Its easier when combining the results (rather than having to deal with IPC because you forked).

Comment: that's the requirements :(
using fork once.

Comment: That's not too terrible.  Just use a pipe to store your results, and have the first child start at the middle and the parent start at the end (until the middle).   Then store your info in a pipe, and have your parent read it, and multiply its results by the result in the pipe.  Make sure you lock the file from the parent in the child process!