# Using fork(), how can I make child process run always first?

Tags: c, linux, process, fork, vfork

Child and parent process execution is parallel and which starts first depends on OS scheduling. But what can be done to start child always before the parent?

This is the pseudo code for my problem,

```
int start_test()
{
   pid_t pid;
   pid = fork();
   if(pid == 0) {
      execv("XXX", XXX);
   } else if(pid > 0) {
     pid = fork();
    if(pid == 0) {
       execv("XXX", XXX);
    } else {
       // Do something
    }
   }
  return 0;
}
int main()
{
   start_test();
   return 0;
}
```

I wants to make first execv execute first than parent creates new process again. Every execv should be in sequence.

Comment: Why do you need to do this?

Comment: You could do `if (fork( ) != 0) sleep(...))`, though it's quite ugly (and needs error checking for `fork( ) == -1`)

Comment: Start child before the parent? what do you mean, to stop execution in the parent after the child starts and then let the child send a signal to it's parent to continue after that?

Comment: @szczurcio it's not only "quite ugly" it's also not guaranteed to have the results you want.

Comment: @jagsgediya perform a Google search on "linux process synchronization".

Comment: Only reasonable way to create external sync mechanism. say parent will  not do any thing until child create a file /mutex etc.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth I want to start the other process by using execv in the child process, again in the parent i am calling fork and starting another process through execv in child. This all processes need to be started in sequence, so once the first child calls the execv, then only parent should call the another fork, and next process should be started. I would like to know if any better solution can be applied for this scenario.

Comment: Do you just want the exec'ed process to *start* before the parent continues, or do you want the child to run to completion?

Comment: @WilliamPursell I dont want to run child to completion. I just want to start the exec'ed process to start before parent continues.

Comment: @jags You are missing the point of Oliver's question.  If you want all of the processes to run serially, then you need to wait until each child completes and you can simply call `wait`.  Even if you guarantee that one child has invoked `exec` before you start another one, there is no guarantee that the first child will do anything at all before the second one starts (or even completes).

Answer (score 7):

I don't really know why people keep telling not to rely on this behaviour, it's actually used a lot in tracing programs (strace, ldtrace, ...).

First, fork your process and get the child pid, stop the child, and resume it in the parent:

```c
pid_t pid = fork();
if (pid == -1)
    abort();
else if (pid == 0) {
    raise(SIGSTOP); // stop the child
} else {
    waitpid(pid, NULL, WUNTRACED); // wait until the child is stopped
    kill(pid, SIGCONT); // resume the child
}
```

Comment: This is a nice technique, but it does nothing to address the race condition.  After the parent send SIGCONT to the child, it has no way of knowing whether or not exec has been invoked in the child.

Comment: @WilliamPursell: indeed, this is only relevant if you want to wait for your child after it has started, but before it exec's. The reason this is mostly used in a ptrace() situation is that ptrace() will stop the child on some conditions, so you still have control over the child.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this thing in case of `pthread` (POSIX thread), but not in case of process.
See, the process scheduling is always in the hands of kernel and that you cannot manipulate explicitly. In a parallel-processing system all processes (whether it is child process, parent process or other zombie process) all are executed in parallel, that you cannot change.
The `sleep()` method could work, but it is very poor approach to be followed.

**1. By making use of signal handling.**

When you `fork()` a new child process, just then you `sleep()` or `pause()` the parent process. Child process will be executed where as the parent process will be in waiting position. And then child process sends custom signal which will be handeled by parent process to continue the execution.
(This is also hectic, because you need to handle signal in program).

**2. By using the system calls.**

By making use of system calls you can handle the process state (ready, suspend, terminate, etc). There are certain shell commands that implicitly uses the system-signal-handling to change the process state/priority. If you know the processID (pid) then you can do:

```
kill -SIGSTOP [pid]
kill -SIGCONT [pid]
```

And in case of c-programming you can do:

```
system("kill -SIGSTOP [pid]"); //pause
```

and

```
system("kill -SIGCONT [pid]"); //resume
```

### [For more reference you can open this page.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2107/how-to-suspend-and-resume-processes)

*Moreover, if you can you specify the actual problem where you are going to implement this thing, i could suggest you suitably.*

Comment: to get the process id you can do: int pid = getpid(); /*returns the pid value of current process*/

Comment: Please see my comment on question in reply to OliverCharlesworth, That is what i actually want to implement.

Answer (score 0):

There is no guarantee for one process to be scheduled before another. Even if you put the parent to `sleep()`, it could very well happen that the child executes first, if other processes have preempted the parent right after the fork. The child and parent can very well run truly in parallel on two CPUs.

Actually, there is no value in doing so. If some kind of synchronization is required between the two processes, use an explicit mechanism like pipes/signals, etc.

**In short: do not write code to rely on behaviour that is not guaranteed.**

Threads provide more mechanisms to synchronize parallel code execution. You might have a look at pthread. Note that threads – different from processes – share resources like memory, etc. which may impose other problems.

Answer (score 0):

Use a binary semaphore with initial value 0. After fork, parent should wait on the semaphore. After child starts, it can signal the semaphore (i.e., make it 1). Then, parent's wait would be over and it will progress.

Comment: The trouble is that the child has to signal the semaphore before it calls exec, so the race condition persists.

Answer (score 0):

In linux if you want the child process run first, you need to use `kernel.sched_child_runs_first` sysctl parameter

Answer (score 0):

Just put wait(0); inside the parent.
So parent will wait until child is done.

```
if(child){
 //do whatever
}
if(parent{
wait(0);
// so whatever
}
```