# Fork() process behaviour

Tags: fork

Say I have a piece of a code

```cpp
#include<stdio.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<sys/types.h>

int main()
{
    pid_t p ; 
    p = fork (); // p is a new process
    // three cases -1, 0 , >0 
    // -1 will report the error 
    //  0 will tell us that the process is created 
    int i =0 ;
    switch(p)
    {
    case -1 : printf("Error; \n");
              break;

    case 0: printf("I am child and my pid is %d",getpid());
            printf("\nMy parent pid is : %d\n",getppid());
            break;

    default:printf("You are inside parent whose pid is %d\n",getpid());  
            for (int i =20 ; i <= 29; i++)
            {
                printf("%d\n",i);
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

This code is giving different outputs in different operating systems. I have Ubuntu 14.04 on my system and OS in our college labs is Red Hat and when we are executing the same program on different machine the output is different.
Output is Like (on my System):

```
You are inside parent whose pid is 5283
20
21
22
23
24
25
26
27
28
29
I am child and my pid is 5284
My parent pid is : 5283
```

and the system which is inside the labs is giving the output like

```
I am child and my pid is 5284
My parent pid is : 5283
You are inside parent whose pid is 5283
20
21
22
23
24
25
26
27
28
29
```

**If we check the program carefully, in my system's output the parent completes the task first and then gives the control to the child process, and on the other system the parent process first creates the child, child first does its task and then resumes back to parent. So what's the difference? Does it depend on the System Architecture or any other parameter like OS. Please let us know**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can the order of execution of fork() be determined?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6696959/can-the-order-of-execution-of-fork-be-determined)

Comment: In short, nothing can be said about the relative order of their execution.
It depends on the scheduling algorithm which the scheduler rely on. In general, many algorithms give the child process a higher priority as in most cases child process is created to run a different program, so that pages are not copied for parent process if it runs first...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It only depends on the system's scheduler. If you launch your program several times on the same machine, the results may differ.

As soon as two processes are concurrently launched, you can't assume an execution order between their instructions.