# i want to know why this c code excute like this

Tags: c, fork

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> // exit
#include <unistd.h> // fork, getpid

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    printf("hello world (pid:%d)\n", (int) getpid());
    int ret_fork = fork();
    if (ret_fork < 0) {
        // fork failed; exit
        fprintf(stderr, "fork failed\n");
        exit(1);
    } else if (ret_fork == 0) {
        // child (new process)
        printf("hello, I am child (pid:%d)\n", (int) getpid());
    } else {
        // parent goes down this path (original process)
        printf("hello, I am parent of %d (pid:%d)\n",
           ret_fork, (int) getpid());
    }
    return 0;
}
```

When I excute this, I got:

```
hello world (pid:3082)
hello, I am parent of 3083 (pid:3082)
hello, I am child (pid:3083)
```

Why are second row is printed faster than third row?

I want to know how it works in sequence.

Comment: There is no sequence. Welcome to the world of multi threaded/processing code. The order is undetermined

Comment: Why shouldn't it be printed faster?

Answer (score 0):

When you use new processes, they all run separately. Your terminal window can only output one at a time, so whichever one gets in first will be put out first. If you run it several times, you may find out that other processes get outputed first, it's just random.

Answer (score 0):

The order is not defined and you shouldn't rely on any order:

> While you cannot control which process (parent or child) gets scheduled first after the `fork` (in fact on SMP/multicore it might be both!) there are many ways to synchronize the two processes [...]

From [Can the order of execution of fork() be determined?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6697626/2005038)

If you need, you should synchronize the two processes with other means.